# Change Matplotlib Plot once it is created?

Tags: matplotlib

I have access to the figure from a matplotlib call plt.scatter(.) but plt.show() is not called yet.

From this point, how can I access the plot and change the color of the scatter points? Is there a way to access the figure and change elements that would have been done during plt.scatter(color=)?

ADD:

Thanks to IBE's comment I was able to, after the plt.scatter() function was called, use the following to change the color of the points:

```
plt.gca().axes.collections[-1].set_color(cols)
```

Comment: Maybe you want to spend some more words on how you created the scatter, why you don't have access to it and, what exactly you want to change and what the desired outcome is?

Comment: Its called as part of an external lib. So especially there is a call plt.scatter(.) which would render if you call plt.show(). My question is how to access the plot and change it before calling plt.show()

Comment: You may access the `PathCollection` created by `scatter` via `ax.collections[-1]` if it is the last thing that is added to the axes `ax`. For everything else, see my first comment.